# Does the value of Stage.stageWidth change as per the screen-resolution, monitor-size, browser etc ?

Tags: actionscript-3

Does the value of Stage.stageWidth or Stage.stageHeight change  as per the screen-resolution, monitor-size, browser etc ?

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not.  The `stageWidth` and `stageHeight` properties always return the dimensions of the visible stage area, regardless of what system the player is running on.

If you want to find out what the actual screen resolution and DPI are, use the [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) class:

```
var screenDPI = Capabilities.screenDPI;
var screenResX = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
var screenResY = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that it's not dependant on any screen specs... A 500x500 stage will still be 500x500 on any screen; albeit different in appearance.